# Rate-limiting for rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rate-limiting

I'm searching rate-limiting engine for my rails 3 application. I've found some but that's not what i need. I 've found rack-throttle gem and curbit gem. It seems that rack-throttle works for each request to rails application but i need to limit requests only to one action. Curbit was last updated two years ago. Can anyone tell me about any other rate-limiting engines  that i can use? Note that it should work with caching.

Comment: what about throttling on the web server (apache?)

Comment: @Rogier
the project will be deployed on heroku

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, finally rack throttle is a good solution.

You can do it the following way. You need to define your custom limiter. It can be based on either of the following limiters

```
Rack::Throttle::Limiter
Rack::Throttle::Interval
Rack::Throttle::Hourly
Rack::Throttle::Daily
```

Everything you need to do is derive from one of the above classes to define custom logic. For example:

```
class CustomLimiter < Rack::Throttle::Interval
  def allowed?(request)
  #custom logic here
  end
end
```

You should put this file in the `RAILS_ROOT/lib` path. Then in the `application.rb` file you should specify what class to use as a limiter. For example if you want to apply limiter only to one action you can do it the following way:

```
#lib/custom_limiter.rb
class CustomLimiter < Rack::Throttle::Interval
  def allowed?(request)
    path_info = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path request.url rescue {}
    if path_info[:controller] == "application" and path_info[:action] == "check_answer"
      super
    else 
      true
    end
  end
end

#config/application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  ... 
  #Set up rate limiting
  config.require "custom_limiter"
  config.middleware.use CustomLimiter, :min => 0.2
  ...
end
```

You may need to take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665634/processing-rack-throttle-exceptions-in-rails-application) into consideration

Hope this will be useful

**UPD:**

you may want to check out another solution: [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack)

Comment: wrong code! change to <code>config.require "custom_failure"</code>

Comment: fixed. everything seems to be ok now

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step. Just to know a bit more about the setup. Are you using a what kind of DB to store the counters?

Comment: Also check out the whitelisted? and blacklisted? methods. https://github.com/datagraph/rack-throttle/blob/master/lib/rack/throttle/limiter.rb#L54-L81

Comment: Got caught on this as well. Make sure you also pass `request.request_method` as a second argument to recognize_path (ex: `recognize_path(request.url, request.request_method)`) if you want to rate limit anything other than just GET requests.

Comment: You might also want to check [Rack::Defense](https://github.com/Sinbadsoft/rack-defense) ([gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-defense)).

Answer (score 2):

`rack-throttle` does what you want. Subclass `Limiter` and define your own `#allowed?` method. Simply return true if the request isn't the action you want the limit and don't count it towards the limit. Take a look at `daily.rb`. Redefine `#cache_set` so it doesn't save those that don't match the route you want to limit.

Comment: I've overrided it, and put the file in the lib directory and restarted the server but it doesn't work. `class CustomLimiter < Rack::Throttle::Limiter
  def allowed?(request)
    true == true
  end
end` The page is opened but the assets are not loaded and i get `ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "403 Forbidden (Rate Limit Exceeded)` So the styles are not applied. In `application.rb` i have `config.middleware.use Rack::Throttle::Interval, :min => 0.2`. What's wrong?